# Can a Cisco AS5350 be used as a Session Border Controller (ip-to-ip)?

Tags: cisco, sip

And how can it be configured as such? We don't need transcoding or anything like that, just something between our switch and the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/iad/ps501/ps503/prod_end-of-life_notice0900aecd804c6e86.html

> The Cisco AS5350XM Universal Gateway can meet service provider and
>   enterprise session-border-controller (SBC) requirements through
>   support for the Cisco Multiservice IP-to-IP Gateway, an integrated
>   Cisco IOS® Software application that facilitates connectivity between
>   independent VoIP and video networks.

You need an IOS release with Multiservice support (now called Cisco Unified Border Element, formally Multiservice IP-to-IP Gateway).

If you go here:

http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/index.jsp

You can click on Search By Feature, and put in Multiservice.  It looks like you need at least IP+ or Enterprise and 12.4 to get that feature on the AS5350XM.

Comment: I have the non-XM version. Is it possible at all?

Comment: No, not with the nonXM.